# What do SUPPORT, RESISTANCE and STOP LOSS mean?

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

The following is a chart from Yahoo for **UAL**. What do you mean by **Support, Resistance and Stop Loss** in this graph?

[image]

Comment: Consider using Google.  These are basic terms and there are countless articles that explain them.  For the most part, Investopedia is a very reliable source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When talking about stocks, we sometimes like to pretend that the prices are completely rational and entirely related to the intrinsic value of the stock. The fact of the matter is that this is not true. In reality, stock prices are affected by human psychology (and human-designed algorithms).

If a stock repeatedly approaches a particular price before turning down again, that price is called "**resistance**" because it resists the stock's path upward. The more times the resistance is tested and holds, the stronger that resistance level is perceived to be by traders, and the harder it is for the stock to break through that level. The reason for this is because traders, assuming the price will fail to break through the resistance level, sell the stock when it approaches that level. That creates a self-fulfilling prophecy. Round numbers such as multiple of $10 can also form resistance levels because people tend to place orders at round dollar amounts.

**Support** is essentially the opposite of resistance and it works the same way. If a stock repeatedly approaches a price from above and then fails to fall below that level, that price point is called support.

In general, when stocks break through support or resistance levels, they tend to continue moving in that direction on "momentum."

A **stop-loss** order is an order to sell your stock if the price falls below a certain level. The reason you'd want to do this is to sell your stock before it loses a much greater amount of value.

Answer (score 0):

Point & Figure charts are useful  for determining support & resistance.  They only track  price change and they ignore time, filtering out  day-to-day market noise.

[image]

[image]

Support levels often become resistance levels:

[image]

A more in depth explanation is available [here](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/technical/03/081303.asp)

Here's a Point & Figure chart for the past 20 months of UAL:

[image]

Comment: This answer is not appropriate for the level of the question.

Comment: Are you implying  that you don't understand the support and resistance levels depicted in the charts posted?

Comment: I do, but I know what support and resistance mean. The OP asks what they mean and this answer doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: I provided a link that provides a detailed explanation  so I think my reply answers the question.  You think it doesn't so therefore, why don't you put in the effort and craft an answer that offers what you think is better explanation?  Step up and earn some points.

Comment: Ok done. Let me know if you think I should add anything.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and you're earning points as well as best answer :->)